# Summing numbers in wordpress loop

Tags: php

I have no idea how can I display a sum of numbers from array. **I work inside wordpress loop.** Here is my code:

```
 <?php 
  $a = array($apples); 
  foreach ($a as $b) 
  { 
  $totalapples = $b . " "; 
  echo "$totalapples";
  }
?>
```

This code display (I have numbers like 4,5 etc.):

```
4,5 13,5 10 13,5 14 12,3 7,5 5,4 9,5 5,4 4,5 4 3,3 5,7
```

Comment: what is the question? how to add the numbers separated by commas?

Comment: No, there are'nt separate by commas. Some number are for example 4,5 (four and half). I need to sum all this number.

Answer (score 0):

To add numbers, use +=.

```
$totalapples = 0;
foreach ($apples as $apple) {
  $totalapples += $apple;
}
```

Comment: There is also `$totalapples = array_sum($apple)` but that's just cheating.